# Scrapy start_urls in text file

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl through urls and retrieve **h1** of each url. The url is stored in a text file. The code is:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "sitemaplocation"
    allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
    f = open("locationlist.txt",'r')
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()


def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    title= sel.xpath("//h1[@class='no-bd']/text()").extract()
    print title
```

The code crawls through the site but doesn't print anything. Any help would be useful.

Comment: Are all of urls in the file from the same domain specified in `allowed_domains`? You should analyze the log to see if any of your requests are filtered.

Answer (score 1):

Try to place this:

```
name = "sitemaplocation"
allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
f = open("locationlist.txt",'r')
start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
f.close()
```

into

```
__init__
```

method in MySpider class.

And also where do you call parse function?

Answer (score 0):

Try inheriting your spider from [`Spider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider) not from [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.